# SQL insert caching

Tags: sql, sql-server, caching

I have a qustion regarding an sql insert. The problem is that if you have a big table with a lot of indexes and a lot of inserts then the inserting of the data is slow. Is it a good approach if I have table A without any indexes and table B with indexes (A and B have the exact same scheme - they are equal) and if I insert everything in table A first and a separate service will work on background and will move all the data to table B where it will be indexed?

Comment: what is the volume of inserts..how did you figured out indexes was the problem

Answer (score 0):

Using a staging table like this is not inconceivable.  In fact, [operational data stores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_data_store) essentially do this.

However, such database structures are usually used for storing incoming data close to the "transactional" format.  The final load into history involves more than just building indexes.

Before going down that path, you need to investigate why inserts are so slow and what is the volume of inserts.  Can you replace some of the inserts with bulk inserts?  Reducing the number of transactions can improve performance.  Are all the indexes needed?  Do you have the optimal data model for your problem?